# Dealing with stale elements when using WebDriver with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, backbone.js

We are using Backbone.js and having issues when running our WebDriver tests. We are getting the following error:

`org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Error Message => 'Element does not exist in cache'`

Our understanding is that this is caused when we are finding an element, and executing an action on that element (e.g. `click()`). The element that we have found has gone 'stale', and we suspect that element has been re-rendered or modified.

We have seen lots of solutions that we are not keen on:

1. Use `Thread.Sleep(...)`. We don't want explicit sleeps in our code
2. Using a retry strategy, either as a loop or try-catching the `StaleElementReferenceException`. We feel this is not the right/clean solution, and is prone to breaking in the future
3. Some people are using `WebDriverWait` and waiting until some javascript function execution returns true. We have seen people wait for `notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback)` in Angular, but can't find anything obvious for Backbone.

We are hoping there is a clean solution that does not involve explicit sleeping, or some form of looping. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not too sure about this, but a potential jQuery equivalent to the angular method you mentioned is `$.ajaxStop`. It takes a function that executes when all ajax requests have returned and their success callbacks executed (meaning your page should be ready).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into `WebDriverWaits` a bit more and I think i've come up with a combination of expectations that works for us:

`wait.until(refreshed(elementToBeClickable(...)));`

The [`refreshed`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-2.45.0/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L619) expectation is a wrapper for other expectations that deals with `StaleElementReferenceException`, and the [`elementToBeClickable`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-2.45.0/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L519) expectation checks the element is clickable. What is interesting is that looking at the source for the built in expectations, some of them deal with `StaleElementReferenceExceptions`, while others don't (e.g. [`presenceOfElementLocated`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-2.45.0/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L101)) and need to be wrapped in the refreshed expectation, so I think that's what initially threw me off when I first looked at `WebDriverWaits`.